# Toggling Bluetooth device discoverable on Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, toggle, device

I'm trying to find a simple way to toggle on and off a devices Bluetooth discoverability on Android via a Checkbox.  Switching it on is simple enough but I don't have any luck with turning if off again.  I'm using a work around for by setting the device to discoverable for a second (a method I found on here on stackoverflow) but I need to find a way of doing it properly.

```
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (buttonView.isChecked()) {
            if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "No Bluetooth Support", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                    if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                            Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
                            discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 0);
                            startActivity(discoverableIntent);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Device Discoverable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
            }
    } else {
            if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                    Intent disablediscoverableIntent = new Intent(
                                    BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
                    disablediscoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 1);
                    startActivity(disablediscoverableIntent);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Discoverable Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately i think this is the only wat offered by the Android API. Isn't it enough ?

Comment: Unfortunately not.  I was wondering if there is a way to do it with out getting security notice...similar to toggling it in the system preferences.